# Change Click Function to hover (Vanilla Javascript)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I am using this code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    document.getElementById("div#logo1").onclick = function(){
        hideAllImages();
        document.getElementById("01").style.display="block";
        removeNavHighlight();
        document.getElementById("div#logo1").classList.add("my_active");
    };
    
    document.getElementById("div#logo2").onclick = function(){
        hideAllImages();
        document.getElementById("02").style.display="block";
        removeNavHighlight();
        document.getElementById("div#logo2").classList.add("my_active");
    };
        document.getElementById("div#logo3").onclick = function(){
        hideAllImages();
        document.getElementById("03").style.display="block";
        removeNavHighlight();
        document.getElementById("div#logo3").classList.add("my_active");
    };

function hideAllImages() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('changing_text');
    var itemsLen = items.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < itemsLen; i++) {
        items[i].style.display="none";
    }
}});
```

Which working fine with click event but I want to convert it to be functional when I hover to the element.

What this function must to: for example, when I hover on an image other element must appear and previous element must become hidden.

This is Vanilla Javascript code.

Any suggestions? tried to change .onclick to .onmouseover but not working.

Comment: use onmouseover

Comment: @shoaibsabir not working

Comment: can you provide only those elements code and your js code

Answer (score 1):

It's not .mouseover it's .onmouseover

Comment: no it's not working with .onmouseover I tried it also

Comment: Add your html to the question please

Comment: I am using Wordpress with Elementor. I have images with corresponding ID and text elements. So there is no html

Answer (score 0):

Is it working for you to replace `.onclick` by `.onmouseover`?

Comment: no it's not working

Answer (score 0):

These functions are always in format `on<event>`. It should be `.onmouseover` as the other answers have already said. Note that you'd be using `mouseover` if you were adding an event listener using the `addEventListener` function.

Comment: I tried .onmouseover also and it's not working

Comment: @Gelebrin7 are you sure you're targeting the correct element?